# ProductController for Mass Action

Tags: adminhtml, controllers, massaction

I am working on a mass action to 'add a category'. I have most of the peripheral things set up correctly. I added 'add a category' to the mass action dropdown and I am returning a full list of my categories in a new dropdown similar to the way the change Status mass action works. I now need to get an Action function working to append categoryids to products.

Heres my module code with the ProductController last

Renderer to use in my observer to ouput categories

```
 class Clr_Categorymassaction_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid_Render_Category extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($row->getEntityId());
        $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
        $allCats = '';
        foreach($cats as $key => $cat)
        {
            $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat);
            $allCats.= $_category->getName();
            if($key < count($cats)-1)
                $allCats.= ',<br />';
        }
        return $allCats;
    }

}
```

Building the category tree

```
class Clr_Categorymassaction_Model_System_Config_Source_Category
{
    public function toOptionArray($addEmpty = true)
    {
        $options = array();
        foreach ($this->load_tree() as $category) {
            $options[$category['value']] =  $category['label'];
        }

        return $options;
    }



    public function buildCategoriesMultiselectValues(Varien_Data_Tree_Node $node, $values, $level = 0)
    {
        $level++;

        $values[$node->getId()]['value'] =  $node->getId();
        $values[$node->getId()]['label'] = str_repeat("--", $level) . $node->getName();

        foreach ($node->getChildren() as $child)
        {
            $values = $this->buildCategoriesMultiselectValues($child, $values, $level);
        }

        return $values;
    }

    public function load_tree()
    {
        $store = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        $parentId = $store ? Mage::app()->getStore($store)->getRootCategoryId() : 1;  // Current store root category

        $tree = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/category_tree')->load();

        $root = $tree->getNodeById($parentId);

        if($root && $root->getId() == 1)
        {
            $root->setName(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Root'));
        }

        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
        ->setStoreId($store)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('is_active');

        $tree->addCollectionData($collection, true);

        return $this->buildCategoriesMultiselectValues($root, array());
    }
}
```

Config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Clr_Categorymassaction>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Clr_Categorymassaction>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <Categorymassaction>
                <class>Clr_Categorymassaction_Model</class>
            </Categorymassaction>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <Categorymassaction>
                <class>Clr_Categorymassaction_Helper</class>
            </Categorymassaction>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <Categorymassaction>
                <class>Clr_Categorymassaction_Block</class>
            </Categorymassaction>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <adminhtml_block_html_before><!--<core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>-->
                <observers>
                    <thisisauniquekey>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Clr_Categorymassaction_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>addCategoryMassAction</method>
                    </thisisauniquekey>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_block_html_before><!--</core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>-->
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Clr_Categorymassaction before="Mage_Adminhtml">Clr_Categorymassaction_Adminhtml</Clr_Categorymassaction>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Just in case I need to use

```
class Clr_Categorymassaction_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Observer

```
<?php

class Clr_Categorymassaction_Model_Observer {
    public function addCategoryMassAction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $block = $observer ->getBlock();
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid) {
            $block->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('Clr_Categorymassaction', array(
                'label'     =>  Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Add to Category'),
                'url'       =>  $block->getUrl('*/*/massCategory', array('_current' => true)),
                'additional'=> array(
                    'visibility'    => array(
                        'name'          =>'Category',
                        'class'         =>'required-entry',
                        'label'         =>Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Categories'),
                        'type'          => 'select',
                        'values'        => Mage::getModel('Categorymassaction/system_config_source_category')->toOptionArray(),
                        'renderer'      => 'Categorymassaction/catalog_product_grid_render_category',

                        )
                    )
                ));
        };
    }


}
```

ProductController

```
class Clr_Categorymassaction_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function massCategoryAction()
    {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $productIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
        $cat = $this->getRequest()->getParam('Category');
        if (!is_array($productIds)) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Please select product(s).'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
        }
        else {
            //convert $cat -> categoryid eg:
            //$this = $category['label']->getCategoryId();
            try {
                foreach($productIds as $product) {
                    // append categoryId to $productId
                    //$product->setCategoryIds($cat);
                    //$product->save();
                   // $cat->setPostedProducts($product);
                }
               //$cat->save();
                //Save product
                }
                catch (Exception $e){
                  $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
                  $this->_redirect('*/*/index'); 
                }
            }
```

I know my controller is in a pitiful state, any direction for how I can get the productIds assigned to the $cat category would be a life saver. Thanks for digging in to the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your controller:

```
$productIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
if (!is_array($productIds)) {
    $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Please select product(s).'));
    $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
}

$catId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('Category');
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);

if (!$category->getId()) {
    $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Category not found.'));
    $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
}

try {
    foreach($productIds as $productId) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

        if (!$product->getId()) {
            continue;
        }

        $productCats = $product->getCategoryIds();
        $productCats = array_unique(array_merge($productCats, array($catId)));

        $product->setCategoryIds($productCats)->save();
    }
} catch (Exception $e){
    $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
    $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
}
```

Comment: StackExchange to the rescue! The only thing I had to add was a redirect back to the catalog product page. $this->_redirect('adminhtml/catalog_product/index/', array());       Thanks Tyler

Comment: So I understand this entire controller except.     if (!$product->getId()) {         continue; }.  What is this doing?

Comment: @Chris That's a sanity check that's making sure the product was found and loaded by that ID. If `$product` is set to an empty instance of the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` class, then `$product->getId()` will resolve as false. In that case, `continue;` just skips ahead to the next iteration of the `foreach`